# Partition function of primon bosonic gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Can we interpret the **Euler product formula** " $\sum\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p\;\mathrm{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} $ " in a stat. physical sense, as a product of single-particle system *partition functions*, considering them *statistically independent* ?

Comment: Clarification: Euler is one of these people with *a lot* of things named after him. We are talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function) Euler's formula, $\sum\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p\;\mathrm{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$, and not some other one that I have not been able to find/ have currently forgotten?

Comment: Yes,exactly this

Comment: What do you mean *"Can we interpret"*? Declare that every one of those functions is a partition function of a system. Done. Are you asking whether there is a "natural" physical system that has those functions as partition functions? Why would that be interesting, or rather, why are you interested in the Euler product formula from a physical viewpoint in the first place. Also, please include the actual formula into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm...OK well lets see what happens.

Lets let $s = \beta\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is some fixed energy and 
$$
Z\left(\frac{s}{\varepsilon}\right) = \zeta(s)
$$.

To get some kind of idea for what kind of system $Z$ describes we need to find the energy levels of the system and to do that we need to express $Z$ in the form $\sum_{i} e^{-\beta E_i}$. In general there will not be a unique way to do this but Euler's formula gives us a couple of obvious ways to try.

The left had side of Euler's formula gives us
\begin{align}
Z(\beta) & = \sum_n n^{-\varepsilon \beta}\\
& = \sum_n e^{-\beta \varepsilon \ln n}
\end{align}.

So we have some system with logarithmically spaced energy levels.

The right hand side we are looking to interpret as a collection of independent, weakly interacting, distinguishable systems with partition functions
$$
Z_p\left(\frac{s}{\varepsilon}\right) = \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
$$.

Again the systems described by $Z_p$ will not in general be unique but there is an obvious binomial expansion to give a geometric series
\begin{align}
Z_p(\beta) &= \sum_n p^{-\beta\varepsilon n}\\
& = \sum_n e^{-\beta\varepsilon n \ln p}
\end{align}
This does at least have a simple interpretation; it is the partition function of a harmonic oscillator with $\hbar\omega_p = \varepsilon \ln p$

Euler's formula tells us that 
$$
Z(\beta) = \prod_{p\;\mathrm{prime}}Z_p(\beta)
$$
So we would expect the system logarithmically spaced energy levels to have the same macroscopic properties as an infinite collection of harmonic oscillators with frequencies in ratios of the logarithms of the primes. Indeed 
\begin{align}
e^{-s\ln n} &= e^{-s\ln p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots}\\
&=e^{-sa_1\ln p_1}e^{-sa_2\ln p_2}\dots
\end{align}
This is precisely the form of the terms obtained by multiplying out the $Z_p$s, which shows that the 2 systems have in fact got the same energy levels (This is essentially a rewriting of proof of Euler's formula on the wiki page)

Now what does this tell us. That's a good question. I cannot this of a naturally occurring system with logarithmically space energy levels, nor can I think where you would find a collection of oscillators with frequencies in radios of $\ln p$, so there doesn't seem to be much physical insight here that I can see. There may also be other ways to expand $Z$ which give different energy levels which may be more interesting. Somebody else may know something I don't.

Comment: Wonderful answer ! And what about fermionic case (when $ a_1, a_2, ...= 0, 1$) ?